# How to remove white space left and right side of page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a footer, but the left and right sides show some white space. How to remove the white space?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    footer {
      background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #DFDFDE;
      padding: 120px 0px;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    .divider {
      background: url('http://evablackdesign.com/wp-content/themes/ebd/images/footer-border.png')
      repeat-x scroll center center transparent;
      height: 7px;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: -6px;
    }
    .container {
      width: 930px;
      margin: 0px auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <footer>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>hiiiiiiiii</h1>
      <br>
      <h2>buyyyyyyyyyyyy</h2>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image of footer](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-qo3hAAwnHNg/U3PRC43T3PI/AAAAAAAAB20/YKwvgD4SGOM/s1600/footer.jpg)

The  tag defines a footer for a document or section.

A  element should contain information about its containing element.

A footer typically contains the author of the document, copyright information, links to terms of use, contact information, etc.

Answer (score 19):

The body has a default margin. Remove it via:

```
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: even better, start your css with a full 'normalize' or reset, something like this: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 4):

Most Web browsers have different default settings for the base margins and padding. This means that if you don't set a margin and padding on your body and html tags, you could get inconsistent results on the page depending upon which browser you're using to view the page.

The best way to solve this is to set all the margins and paddings on the html and body tags to 0:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
*{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your body has a default margin and padding and you need to override it.
At the beginning of your style type.

```
body{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what `box-sizing` is?

Comment: you can check this link => [box-siziing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) it is explained very good.

Comment: Yes but can you explain how it helps in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style tag...

```
body {
  margin: 0;    
}
```

Comment: Not all browsers use body margin for this; see j08691's answer for a more reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to add this class to your CSS style.

```
.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this; it is the simplest one, add it to your body selector.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, It's working

```html
 html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if ur having unwanted white space in right side of ur screen its because of overflow so to remove it go to ur css then in body write

```
in css:
(body{
  width:100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
})
```

[this is before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcXva.png)

[this is after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eohuO.png)

this is my first help i am new to stackoverflow hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if margin 0 is not working on body then try this

```
.container-fluid {
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```